# Convert a LinkButton to behave like an Label control in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a repeater control in my page, let me show you

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrSectionGrid" OnItemDataBound="rptrSectionGrid_OnItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<!-- Accordion card -->
<div class="card">
.....
....
....
<!-- the mark up that I want to fix ... -->
<span class="pull-right">
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="imgBtnDeleteSection" CssClass="section-delete-icon delete-section" AlternateText=""></asp:Label>
   <span id="qcount" class="question-count" style="width: 100px; display: inline-block;"><%# Eval("total_section_question") %> questions</span>
   <span class="question-count" style="width: 75px; display: inline-block;"><%# Eval("total_section_time_mint") %> Minutes</span>
</span>
```

as you could see , there is a Label control nested inside **`<span class="pull-right">`**.

Now please look at this DOM,

[image]

Now I want this Label control to behave like a button, so what I had done , is replace that Label into a LinkButton and by doing so its rendering like this,

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrSectionGrid" OnItemDataBound="rptrSectionGrid_OnItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<!-- Accordion card -->
<div class="card">
.....
....
....
<!-- the mark up that I want to fix ...-->
<span class="pull-right">
   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="imgBtnDeleteSection" OnClick="imgBtnDeleteSection_OnClick" CssClass="section-delete-icon delete-section" AlternateText=""></asp:LinkButton>
   <span id="qcount" class="question-count" style="width: 100px; display: inline-block;"><%# Eval("total_section_question") %> questions</span>
   <span class="question-count" style="width: 75px; display: inline-block;"><%# Eval("total_section_time_mint") %> Minutes</span>
</span>
```

[image]

What I want is, my LinkButton should be nested inside that **`<span class="pull-right">`**

Please help me to fix this issue ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: LinkButton is an .Net server control and it is not possible to show within the DOM because it just renders the HTML content. If you have used the LinkButton in your HTML code in asp.net, after running this page you will get its HTML markup only.